# Life-size building floor plan

Tags: software-recommendation, projector

I need to develop a life-size building plan, I will prepare a floor plan from any Autocad software and later send it to 6 different projectors to get a Life-size building floor plan so that the end customers can have a walkthrough of their house. it will be a 2D effect only.

Which software can help me send my floor plan to 6 projectors?

How will this entire thing work. Please share some views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use video projection mapping software, and 3D rendering software. [Mad Mapper](https://madmapper.com/) is a well known projection mapping application.
[Blender](http://blender.org) or [Cinema4D](https://www.maxon.net/en/cinema-4d) would do the 3D rendering.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I would like to know whether the projection mapping application also helps in point correction and overlapping intensity adjustments. I would like to know more about the software and its features used to develop the life-size building floor plan as shown in this URL https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aejn1GERcYY

Comment: There's one called Resolume that's used for concerts and live events.  Part of the software is for projection mapping images to unusually-shaped displays and projection screens, but it also includes a lot of features for timing and controlling lights via DMX, which you might not need.  https://resolume.com/software